# Retrieve users detail through WP REST API using access token of Auth0?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, api, rest

Using [Auth0 plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/auth0/) in Wordpress I have authorized new users and got the access token by reading [Auth0 documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/auth-api#!#post--oauth-ro)

Now I want to retrieve users through [wp rest api retrieve users](http://wp-api.org/#users_retrieve-users) which need authentication. Can i use access token of Auth0 to retrieve users details.

Even I think that to integrate the Auth0 and WP REST API we need to use [JWT Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-jwt-auth/). So that I can use wp rest api.

> Is this Right way to get with the help of JWT plugin or am i on wrong path?

It would be great if there would be any related example for using this.